# How to map on-premise server cores to vcores for Azure Sql Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-configuration

We are migrating our database to Azure Sql database. We have chosen a vCore purchasing model. How to make the exact mapping of on-premise cores to vcores on Azure ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking this from a licensing standpoint?  If so, you best option is to look at the Azure Hybrid Benefit Calculator.  There is a tab specifically for Azure SQL that will help you understand what you can use under the benefit.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/hybrid-benefit/#calculator

If you are looking just of sizing guidance, please look at the **Data Migration Assistant**.  It can help to assess your current configuration and give recommendations on sizing based of utilization, not current configuration on-prem.  The reason for this is most organizations over-provision their servers on-prem to account for peak-load.  In the cloud, you should utilize auto-scaling to meet demand.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you for the response. I guess my question was not clear. We are currently premise. Our machine configuration, for example, is 4*12 cores @3.0 GHz.  In Azure, we are choosing vCore purchase model. I now want to choose the right instance configuration.. for example 8vCore , 12 vCore etc.. how to make the right selection ?

Comment: The is no easy answer.  The biggest issue is that when on premises you typically over provision a machine to account for peak load.  In the cloud you should try your best to scale to meet load requirements.  I would suggest using the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15.  I will update answer to reflect this.